# Understanding the Jordan form via this example

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

### The Question:

I do not understand why the Jordan Form of the matrix:
$A:=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$ is: $J:=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$?

### Here is what I have done so far:

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by:
$\phi(t)=t^2-4t+4$ and $v:=(1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$.

However my issue is that $(A-2I)v=0$, but apparently $v$ is part of a length $2$ cycle of generalised eigenvectors, how do I find the other member of this cycle of eigenvectors?

Comment: This should help, check out this answer:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262436/finding-jordan-form-of-a-specific-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can work backwards.

if $A$ is similar to $J,$  then there is a nonsingular matrix $P$ made up columns $u, v$ so that $$A[u,v]= [u,v]J=[u,v]\pmatrix{2&1\\0&2}$$ this is equivalent to two equations $$(A-2I)u = 0, (A-2I)v = u.$$ the vector $v$ is called the generalized eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $2.$ the chain $u, v$ is called the jordan chain of length $2$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $2.$

---

we have $$A - 2I= \pmatrix{-1&1\\-1&1}, u = \pmatrix{1\\1}$$ to find the generalized eigenvector $v$, we will solve the system $$\pmatrix{-1&1&|&1\\-1&1&|&1}\to \pmatrix{-1&1&|&1\\0&0&|&0}$$  so $$v = \pmatrix{0\\1}$$ will do and $$\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&3}\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}= \pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}\pmatrix{2&1\\0&2} \to \\\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&3}=\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}\pmatrix{2&1\\0&2}\pmatrix{1&-1\\0&1} $$

Comment: Perfect answer you've finally demystified the Jordan form for me entirely :D

Answer (score 4):

Alternative explanation

---

We have the matrix $A$, that we want to put into Jordan form $J$.
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$$

What are the eigenvalues?
$$(1-\lambda)(3-\lambda)+1=0\iff \lambda^2-4\lambda+4=0\iff (\lambda-2)^2=0$$
Hence we have repeated eigenvalues at $2$.

A Jordan normal form of size $2\times 2$ takes the following forms:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\mu\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\lambda\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1\\0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $\lambda\ne \mu$ and $\lambda,\mu$ are eigenvalues. Hence we have either:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\text{, or }\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Can $A$ be diagonalized though? The answer is no. If it were diagonalizable, we would obtain the first of the two options above, and hence we must have the second:

$$A= S\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&2 \end{bmatrix}S^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ker(A-2I)\varsubsetneq\ker(A-2I)^2 \cong\mathbf R^2$, all you have to do is solve for the equation $(A-2I)\cdot u=v$, so that 
$$Av=2v, \quad Au=2u+v,$$
hence the matrix of $A$ in the $(v,u)$ basis will be $\,\begin{bmatrix} 2&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Bernard :)

Answer (score 0):

Just  solve the equation
$$
Au = 2u+v.
$$

Then, the matrix in the base $(u,v)$ will be $J^T$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution mookid!